# Как правильно просклонять: улицы Советской или Советская?

Tags: склонение

Подскажите, как правильно: на пересечении улицы Советской или Советская с улицей Железнодорожной или Железнодорожная. К какому справочнику нужно обратиться?

Answer (score 4):

Правильно: "на пересечении Советской и Железнодорожной улиц". 
Или: "Советской улицы с Железнодорожной (улицей)".
При таком порядке и вопрос склонения отпадает сам собой.
В отношении же инверсного варианта (улица Советская), то его без особой нужды лучше не употреблять, это канцеляризм. Хотя склонять все равно придётся.

Но: "улица Попова", "улица Герцена" и проч. Тогда: "на пересечении улицы Попова c (улицей) Герцена.

*Почему-то вспоминается старый одесский анекдот про таксиста, который отказывался везти пассажира на "угол двух Карлов". Были в Одессе две такие улицы: Маркса и Либкнехта, обе ныне переименованы. Вся соль анекдота в том, что улицы идут параллельно.*